# Finding radius of convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality

I have gotten the problem *almost* solved, but I'm hung up on how to solve this inequality:

$$|x|/|2x+1|<1 $$

I could move the denominator to the right side of the equation:

$$|x|<|2x+1|$$

But where to go from there? I'm not sure how to proceed. For reference, I'm trying to find the radius of convergence.

Comment: $$x^2<4x^2+4x+1$$
$$0<3x^2+4x+1$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $x$ to real,  $$\left|\frac x{2x+1}\right|<1\iff \left(\frac x{2x+1}\right)^2<1$$

$$\iff x^2<(2x+1)^2\iff(2x+1-x)(2x+1+x)>0$$

$$\iff(x+1)\left(x+\frac13\right)>0$$

Now, $(x-a)(x-b)>0$ with $a<b\implies$ either $x<a$ or $x>b$